# "Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe" when trying to run app on Android device

Tags: android, android-debug

Trying to develop my first app, and I'm running some code on a Nexus 6. Android Studio tells me I have no errors, but when I try to run the app on my phone, I only see a blank skin (i.e just the title of the app in the ActionBar and everything blank underneath)

I checked the logcat and it said: "Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe"

I tried googling around for this error but didn't find anything that helped. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: have you checked out this solution :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830024/continuing-problems-running-android-apps

Comment: That's the only line in your logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Compiler SDK** version and the **Emulator API** version. 
If the compiler SDK version greater than API version it will throw the Error.

Comment: Where can we check the sdk compiler?

Answer (score -3):

Under gradle scripts you can check compiler version.

In build.gradle(module app)

Comment: This is not an answer to the main question on the page. You can first earn 50 reputations and get access to comments. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Answer (score -3):

There should be problem with Layouts you implemented for your app , check opacity of frame color you used .

I also got similar issues , but i fixed that with correct layout.