# Try to add a picture marker google maps with android studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-drawable, marker

I tried to add a `drawable` in a marker google maps but it doesn't worked.
I followed many tutorials and tried many things without success...
Anyone can help me ?

this is my code :

> I think the problem is ".icon(icon)"

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_radar);

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney").icon(icon));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to first change it to `BitmapDrawable` then convert into `Bitmap`, then only you can add image to a `marker`, do it something like this:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    Bitmap b=bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
    Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 84, 84, false);

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker)));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: thanks for your help but it doesn't work, application close when it start and no error message this time :/

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work because the drawable is a vector, no ?

Comment: I have tested it with .png icons.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_radar);
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the application close when it start : I have this error --> Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe

Comment: @GregConstantin refer to this link for your error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40010794/4832356